# StackOverFlow - Exception caught by widgets library

Tags: android, linux

I am learning Dart with Flutter, so today i am writing a small stateful Quizz app (the kind where you simply tap either a green TRUE button or a red FALSE button to answer some questions.

Its basicly each question paired with a true or false boolean value.

The code is below. It consists only of *material.dart* and a separate class, called *QuizBrain.dart*.

QuizBrain contains the questions and a constructor for the question/boolean pair.

The first function contains only the AppBar, the backgroundColor and the body:SafeArea with a call to **Quizzler2()** - this is actually the important function, which will extend StatefulWidget below material.dart

The value int index is simply the counter index for each question/bool pair.

! I am romanian, so the name of some variables and the Strings are in romanian.

My problem --- this app actually used to work great!
*Until* i tried to move the int index=0  into the QuizBrain.dart file ...and then back out again!

W..T..F !!!

After this, every time i try to run the app, Android Studio (i run Android on linux), returns me a massive wall of text of error:

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following StackOverflowError was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size:
> Size(480.0, 1013.3), devicePixelRatio: 3.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0,
> platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
> viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
> alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false,
> highContrast: false, disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false,
> boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional, gestureSettings:
> DeviceGestureSettings(touchSlop: 8.0))): Stack Overflow

Ofcourse, i ran  dart clear cache and flutter clean cache...to no avail!

I did noticed other uses with StackOverFlow errors...but my situation is nothing like theirs!

I have MaterialApp !

So...whats wrong ?!

=========================================================================

The **material.dart** code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'QuizBrain.dart';



void main()
{
  runApp(QuizzlerTest());
}


class QuizzlerTest extends StatelessWidget
{  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {  
    return MaterialApp
      ( 

      home: Scaffold
        ( 
        appBar: AppBar
          (  
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          title: Text('Quizzler TEST', style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 35,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),),

        ),  

        backgroundColor: Colors.black,

        body: SafeArea
          ( 
          child: Padding
            (  
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            child: Quizzler2(),

          ), 
        ),  
      ), 
      );  
  } 

}  


class Quizzler2 extends StatefulWidget
{ 
  @override
  _Quizzler2State createState() => _Quizzler2State();
} 


class _Quizzler2State extends State<Quizzler2>
{  

  int index = 0;
  QuizBrain Creier = QuizBrain();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {  
    return Column
      (  
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children:<Widget>
        [  
          Expanded
            ( 
            flex: 5,
            child: Padding
              (
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Center
                ( 
                child: Container
                (
                  child: Text
                    (
                    Creier.listaIntrebarilor[index].Intrebarile,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle( fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white,),
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ), 
          ),/

          Expanded
            (
            flex: 1,
            child: Container
              ( /
              color: Colors.green,
              child:TextButton
                (
                  onPressed:(){ 
                    bool dilema = Creier.listaIntrebarilor[index].Evaluarea;

                    if(dilema == true)
                    {
                      print('VERDE 1 --- User got it right!');
                    }
                    else if(dilema != true)
                    {
                      print('VERDE 2 --- User got it WRONG!');
                    }

                    setState((){
                      index = index++;
                    });


                  }, /* onPressed ---- end */
                  child: Text('TRUE',
                    textAlign:TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,),
                  )

              ),
            ),

          ),

          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
                  ),

          Expanded
            (
            flex: 1,
            child: Container
              ( 
              color: Colors.red,

              child:TextButton
                (
                  onPressed:(){

                    bool XXX = Creier.listaIntrebarilor[index].Evaluarea;

                    if(XXX == false)
                    {
                      print('ROSU 1 --- User has it right!');
                    }
                    else if (XXX != false)
                    {
                      print(' ROSU 2 --- User has it wrong!');
                    }

                    setState((){
                      index = index++;
                    });

                  }, 
                  child: Text('FALSE',
                    textAlign:TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white,),
                  )

              ),
            ), 
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),

        ]  
    ); /
  }
}
```

=============================================================

And now, the QuizBrain.dart file:

```
class QuizBrain
{ 


  String Intrebarile = '';
  bool Evaluarea = false;

  QuizBrain({String intrebari ='', bool evaluare = false})
  {
    Intrebarile = intrebari;
    Evaluarea = evaluare;
  }

  List<QuizBrain> listaIntrebarilor = [
    QuizBrain (intrebari:'Este sangele rosu?', evaluare: true),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'Melcul zboara ?', evaluare: false),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'0 + 1 = 3', evaluare: false),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'Pestele inoata?', evaluare: true),
                                      ];   


}
```

==================================

Comment: Also ...Android Studio inspector detects no problem with the code at all!   Only when i run it, does the StackOverFlow error appears!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `listaIntrebarilor` to `static` or move it from the `QuizBrain` class. Because now it is a recursive call. For each `QuizBrain (intrebari:'Este sangele rosu?', evaluare: true)` dart create new `QuizBrain` instance with own `listaIntrebarilor` with new `QuizBrain` instance and so on.

```dart
class QuizBrain { 
  String Intrebarile = '';
  bool Evaluarea = false;

  QuizBrain({String intrebari ='', bool evaluare = false}) {
    Intrebarile = intrebari;
    Evaluarea = evaluare;
  }

  static List<QuizBrain> listaIntrebarilor = [
    QuizBrain (intrebari:'Este sangele rosu?', evaluare: true),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'Melcul zboara ?', evaluare: false),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'0 + 1 = 3', evaluare: false),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'Pestele inoata?', evaluare: true),
  ];   
}
```

or

```dart
class QuizBrain { 
  String Intrebarile = '';
  bool Evaluarea = false;

  QuizBrain({String intrebari ='', bool evaluare = false}) {
    Intrebarile = intrebari;
    Evaluarea = evaluare;
  }  
} 

List<QuizBrain> listaIntrebarilor = [
    QuizBrain (intrebari:'Este sangele rosu?', evaluare: true),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'Melcul zboara ?', evaluare: false),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'0 + 1 = 3', evaluare: false),
    QuizBrain(intrebari:'Pestele inoata?', evaluare: true),
];
```